# sync data between two postgres database tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbvisualizer

I have a db1 table A, and db2 table B
i want to insert only non-existing rows from table A to table B and if data already exist in table B, update it.
what is the best way to perform this? i have hundreds of rows to insert and update and many tables. i’m using dbvisualizer. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "already exist" mean?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a `not exists` subquery.  Something like this:

```
insert into b (col1, . . . )
    select col1, . . . 
    from a
    where not exists (select 1 from b where b.? = a.?);
```

There are other methods.  If you have a `unique` constraint/index on `b` that defines uniqueness, then you might want an `on conflict` clause instead.  If you are trying to prevent duplicates, then a `unique` constraint/index is the correct solution.